# Подскажите по функции работы со строкой

Tags: php, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать функцию Gol на php по обработке строки вида "36,67,90,90". Это минуты забитых голов в футбольном матче.  Вызов типа  Gol($stroka,67,2). Это строка, начиная с 67й минуты и забито (начиная с этой минуты) не меньше 2х голов (или больше). Если эта строка подпадает под этот Критерий, то вернуть 1, или 0 если не забито не меньше 2х голов начиная с 67 минуты. Учесть также что может быть пустая строка (если счёт 0:0 к примеру ).

Comment: 1. разбить строку по зяпятой в массив. 2. Отфильтровать массив по условию времени 3. Подсчитать количество элементов. 4. Сравнить с параметром

Comment: Ещё бы это в виде кода. И супер. А то скрипт готовый есть, а как написать эту логику в виде кода незнаю (

Answer (score 1):

Собственно суть такая же, как написал Total Pusher в комментариях к вашему вопросу.

```php
/**
 * @param string $str строка с минутами забитых голов
 * @param integer $minute минута, начиная с которой нужно считать голы
 * @param integer $number количество голов
 */
function goal($str, $minute, $number)
{
    $goals = explode(',', $str);
    $result = array_filter($goals, function($var) use ($minute) {
        return $var >= $minute;
    });
    return count($result) >= $number;
}

goal('36,67,90,90', 67, 2); // true
```